# CSS Responsive Web Design for HTML Stacking Columns in Same Section

Tags: html, css

I currently have two columns which are within one section. They are both separated into their own articles. So it kind of looks like this (a snippet of the body):

```
<section>
     <article class="col1">
     </article>
     <article class="col2">
     </article>
</section>
<aside>
</aside>
```

And within the two articles there are its own text, images, headings, etc.

However currently I have linked a css style sheet to the html. And I am trying to work on the responsive web design. So when I reduce the available pixels, I want the second column (the second article) to collapse and stack underneath the other article when there are less pixels available.

So In order to do this I have done the media query things. I have tried this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.col1{
    display: block;
    width = 100%;
    float: left;
}
.col2{
    display: block;
    width = 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

However this does not work. I am in firefox trying out the web developer tool, and when it goes past 600 pixels, it does not actually collapse. In fact the two columns will exist, and the columns will get cut off.

Basically the task I was allocated was, "Allow for multiple devices. If it's loaded on a mobile device (eg. iPhone), hide the aside and have the columns stack."

Comment: `width = 100%:` won't work in CSS. It should be `width: 100%;`

Comment: okok @zeropublix thanks. ALSO, does it matter if you use # or . before the tag

Comment: is it # before id and . before classes?

Comment: exactly. `#` referes to an ID (which should be unique on the whole page) and `.` to a class (which can occur multiple times)

Answer (score 3):

You have error in your css code. It should be `width: 100%` not `width = 100%`. Try this code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.col1{
    display: block;
    width : 100%;
}
.col2{
    display: block;
    width : 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you check if it actually works or just copy my comment?

Comment: I cannot find any answer to my question.

Comment: you have your answer in my comment. find it yourself